# Add arguments to argparse depending on value of initial arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I know similar questions have been asked before but I could not really find an exact one (also, I could not understand the 'nargs' or 'subparse' concept and how it would apply to my case)

I want something like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-mode', choices=['download', 'upload'], required=True)
parser.add_argument('-d', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.mode == 'download':
    parser.add_argument('-f', required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

so the `-f` argument is required only when the `-mode` is `download` otherwise it should not be parsed

Comment: `argparse` does not have mutually inclusive arguments, which is what you are talking about. You should instead make neither `-d` nor `-f` be required, but include in the usage message the fact that either both or neither must be specified, then check to make sure that both `-d` and `-f` are specified if either is.

Comment: You could use [subparsers](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers), so that `download` becomes a subcommand with it's own set of (required) flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this?

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-mode', choices=['download', 'upload'], required=True)
parser.add_argument('-d', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-f')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.mode == 'download' and not args.f:
    parser.error('-f argument is required in "download" mode.')
```

DEMO:

```
$ python test.py -mode=upload -d 10
$ python test.py -mode=download -d 10
usage: test.py [-h] -mode {download,upload} -d D [-f F]
test.py: error: -f argument is required in "download" mode.
$ python test.py -mode=download -d 10 -f 10
```

Answer (score 8):

Generally, you should avoid making `--options` required. In this case, I would suggest the following:

1. Replace `--mode` with a subcommand.
2. Replace `-d` with a positional argument
3. Replace `-f` with a 2nd positional argument for the `download` command only.

If you really want to, you can keep `-d` and `-f` instead of making them positional arguments.

Your calls would look like this:

```
./script.py upload d-argument
./script.py download d-argument f-argument
```

or

```
./script.py upload -d foo
./script.py download -d foo -f bar
```

The code to implement is a little tedious, but fairly straightforward.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
upload_parser = subparsers.add_parser('upload')
download_parser = subparsers.add_parser('download')
upload_parser.set_defaults(cmd='upload')
download_parser.set_defaults(cmd='download')
for p in [ upload_parser, download_parser ]:
    p.add_argument("d")
    # p.add_argument("-d", required=True)
download_parser.add_argument("f")
# download_parser.add_argument("-f", required=True)


args = parser.parse_args()
if args.cmd == 'upload':
    # handle upload with args.d
elif args.cmd == 'download':
    # handle download with args.d and args.f
```

Note the calls to `set_defaults` used to mark in the final parsed arguments which command was used.

Comment: Great, thanks. Not sure if this happens only for my my python version (3.5), but I need to check if `cmd` in `args` in case the user calls the script without `cmd`.

Comment: If your script is called with no positional arguments, `argparse` itself will raise an error. Otherwise, the first argument will be used for `cmd`.